# Strange flickering with WebView after setting android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Tags: android, webview, flicker

Strange flickering with WebView after setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` and `mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)`

A no one, no flicker.

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled the hardware acceleration for the application and have disabled it for the activity. Additionally I set the background to "null", as mentioned above. It works for me now. Another approach (untested): set the layer type to software rendering and set the background to Color.TRANSPARENT (or "0"): `webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Comment: Thanks, it can solve the flicker problem, but will cause the scrolling Caton,is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

**Do not hard code the flag in code**, it is not a best practice!
you can enable the function in four levels。

Window level:

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

View Level:

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Activity Level:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity ... />
    <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

Applecation Level:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

ref http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html